# How to alter table with ALGORITHM=INSTANT after dropping fulltext index

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table lets say `my_table` with the following fields:

- id (int)
- title (varchar)
- content (text)

And a FULLTEXT index on `title` and on `title + content` Let's call those indexes `index_text_1` and `index_text_2` which aren't required anymore and can be dropped.

Now I want to alter the table, with the `ALGORITHM=INSTANT` so I have:

```
DROP INDEX index_text_1 ON my_table LOCK=NONE;
DROP INDEX index_text_2 ON my_table LOCK=NONE;

ALTER TABLE my_table ADD new_field VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, ALGORITHM=INSTANT
```

This operations will fail with the following message:

```
[0A000][1845] ALGORITHM=INSTANT is not supported for this operation. Try ALGORITHM=COPY/INPLACE.
```

But if I add a `OPTIMIZE TABLE` in before the alter the query just executes.

```
DROP INDEX index_text_1 ON my_table LOCK=NONE;
DROP INDEX index_text_2 ON my_table LOCK=NONE;
OPTIMIZE TABLE my_table;
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD new_field VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, ALGORITHM=INSTANT
```

My question is, can I estimate how long the `OPTIMIZE TABLE` will take (and lock) the table? Or is there any other way to do this without locking the database? The table has around 5.000.000 records and is 4GiB and is running on MySQL 8.0

The documentations says

> OPTIMIZE TABLE is completed in place. An exclusive table lock is only
> taken briefly during the prepare phase and the commit phase of the
> operation. During the prepare phase, metadata is updated and an
> intermediate table is created. During the commit phase, table metadata
> changes are committed.

But what does briefly means here?

Comment: Which statement got the error message?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE my_table ADD new_field VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, ALGORITHM=INSTANT`